# Trying to load a different kernel on CentOS, but always the same one is loaded

Tags: linux, boot, centos

I need to run a virtual machine inside a CentOS 7.7.1908 server. I only have access by SSH. I tried KVM, Virtualbox, OpenVz, Xen, but failed. All of them need to load a different kernel and I realized I'm just unable to load any different kernels. Either by trying to install one of those vm's or by installing any kernel package from update or elrepo repositories, everytime I reboot it loads the same: **3.10.0-042stab141.3**

I couldn't find any bootloaders, so I installed GRUB 2. This kernel doesn't show up on grub.cfg file, even if I recreate the file. I tried to set a default kernel, but I reboot and nothing changes. I tried to load a different kernel just for the next boot, but nothing changes.

I cannot find this kernel on /boot/

I don't know what what else to try.

**hostnamectl** gives me:

```
Chassis: container
Machine ID: b85d4abef7d544958ba92cb29fb0faab
Boot ID: 51d977ef2a0e4a6d9366df5ec0f32416
Virtualization: openvz
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-042stab141.3
Architecture: x86-64
```

**rpm -q kernel** gives me:

```
kernel-3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7.x86_64
```

Running **grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg** gives me:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7.x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7.x86_64.img
done
```

Running **grubby --default-kernel** gives me:

```
/boot/vmlinuz-3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7.x86_64
```

Packages and distro are updated. Doesn't have a **/etc/default/grub** file.

Comment: Where are you running that hostnamectl command? If that is from the host you are SSHing to it means it's an openvz container. I don't know if it's possible to run virtualization inside such a container.

Comment: I wasn't aware of containers before. Did some research, seems you are right.